# How to resolve - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ZMQContext' not found?

Tags: php, zeromq, failed-installation

I have successfully installed ZeroMQ in WAMP, see the screenshot below.

However I am getting Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ZMQContext' not found in C:\wamp64\www\0MQ\zguide\examples\PHP\hwclient.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\wamp64\www\0MQ\zguide\examples\PHP\hwclient.php on line 9

when I run a test script in a browser:

[image]

TEST SCRIPT:

```
<?php
/*
 *  Hello World client
 *  Connects REQ socket to tcp://localhost:5555
 *  Sends "Hello" to server, expects "World" back
 * @author Ian Barber <ian(dot)barber(at)gmail(dot)com>
 */

 $context = new ZMQContext();

 //  Socket to talk to server
 echo "Connecting to hello world server...\n";
 $requester = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_REQ);
 $requester->connect("tcp://localhost:5555");

 for ($request_nbr = 0; $request_nbr != 10; $request_nbr++) {
    printf ("Sending request %d...\n", $request_nbr);
    $requester->send("Hello");

    $reply = $requester->recv();
     printf ("Received reply %d: [%s]\n", $request_nbr, $reply);
}
```

How may I deal with this?

Comment: Would you kindly start the installation inspection procedure, right from a reach-ability test and printing the actual outputs from a call to `void zmq_version( &major, &minor, &patch )`?

Comment: @user3666197 kindly outline the steps to follow. I am just beginning to learn this

Comment: @user3666197, I ran this script to Check if zeromq is installed and tell me the version `<?php

if (class_exists("ZMQ") && defined("ZMQ::LIBZMQ_VER")) {
    echo ZMQ::LIBZMQ_VER, PHP_EOL;
}` and I got **4.1.3 **

Answer (score 0):

I added this configuration line:

```
[ZMQ]
extension=php_zmq.dll
```

to **`php.ini`** located in:

```
c:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9\php.ini
```

rather than in:

```
c:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.27\bin\php.ini
```

This solved the problem.